# How to create and check authorization policy in runtime?

Tags: asp.net

I want to let only the project manager has the right to access the corresponding project data, not other projects. But the project entities are stored in database, it means I need to assign authrization of this project dynamically. But typically the authorization policy is settled in compile time, how to assign and check it in runtime?

Comment: not understanding , why not just assign the pm a role.  then  check for that role in your authorization scheme

Comment: Because I want the manager have the access only this project, not others.